# how do I build a fixed card containing dynamic parts with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to build a dynamic content card using angularJS.

The card has a fixed height and width, and it contains 4 optional parts that appear one after another (**image**, **header**, **tags list**, **content**).
All of the parts are optional and prioritized, meaning:

**1**. If there is an image - it would take up a fixed height.

**2**. If there is a header - it would take up a dynamic height: the entire space it needs within the card, leaving a room for 1 line of tags and 1 line of content.

I tried several methods, including using `overflow:hidden`, `text-overflow: ellipsis;` but nothing seems to work, I even tried using the `md-card` element within angular material, but it does not provide any dynamic text ellipsis.

Here is the basic DOM structure:

`<div class="card">
    <div class="image"><img ng-src={{ vm.image }}></div>
    <div class="header">{{ vm.header }}</div>
    <div class="tags">{{ vm.tagsList }}</div>
    <div class="content">{{ vm.content }}</div>
</div>`

The trick is to make the parts dynamically take up the space they need according to the 2 rules I mentioned above. After waisting 2 days with no luck, Any help would be well appreciated...

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or a fiddle? Let's see what you have.